# C malloc "can't allocate region" error, but can't repro with GDB?

Tags: c, multithreading

How can I debug a C application that does not crash when attached with `gdb` and `run` inside of gdb?

It crashes consistently when run standalone - even the same debug build!

---

A few of us are getting this error with a C program written for BSD/Linux, and we are compiling on macOS with OpenSSL.

```
app(37457,0x7000017c7000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=13835058055282167808) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ERROR: malloc(buf->length + 1) failed!
```

I know, not helpful.

Recompiling the application with `-g -rdynamic` gives the same error.  Ok, so now we know it isn't because of a release build as it continues to fail.

It works when running within a `gdb` debugging session though!!

```
$ sudo gdb app
(gdb) b malloc_error_break
Function "malloc_error_break" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (malloc_error_break) pending.
(gdb) run -threads 8
Starting program: ~/code/app/app -threads 8
[New Thread 0x1903 of process 45436]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)
```

And it runs for hours.  CTRL-C, and run `./app -threads 8` and it crashes after a second or two (a few million iterations).

Obviously there's an issue within one of the threads.  But those workers for the threads are pretty big (a few hundred lines of code).  Nothing stands out.

Note that the threads iterate over loops of about 20 million per second.

- macOS 10.12.3
- Homebrew w/GNU gcc and openssl (linking to crypto)

---

Ps, not familiar with C too much - especially any type of debugging.  Be kind and expressive/verbose in answers.  :)

Comment: This definitely looks suspicious: `mach_vm_map(size=13835058055282167808)` Seems to me, that `buf->length` is uninitialized or corrupted. Considering it's a multithreading process, I would start by looking carefully for all shared variables/memory between threads and double-check, that proper locking/synchronization is in place. Overall it sounds like a typical race condition. In this case, external tools are often not helpful, because they slow down the process enough to hide the problem.

Comment: I'd try valgrind, before doing anything else...

Answer (score 3):

One debugging technique that is sometimes overlooked is to include debug prints in the code, of course it has it's disadvantages, but also it has advantages. A thing you must keep in mind though in the face of abnormal termination is to make sure the printouts actually get printed. Often it's enough to print to `stderr` (but if that doesn't make the trick one may need to `fflush` the stream explicitly).

Another trick is to stop the program before the error occurs. This requires you to know when the program is about to crash, preferably as close as possible. You do this by using raise:

```
raise(SIGSTOP);
```

This does not terminate the program, it just suspends execution. Now you can attach with `gdb` using the command `gdb <program-name> <pid>` (use `ps` to find the pid of the process). Now in `gdb` you have to tell it to ignore `SIGSTOP`:

```
> handle SIGSTOP ignore
```

Then you can set break-points. You can also step out of the `raise` function using the `finish` command (may have to be issued multiple times to return to your code).

This technique makes the program have normal behaviour up to the time you decide to stop it, hopefully the final part when running under `gdb` would not alter the behavior enuogh.

A third option is to use `valgrind`. Normally when you see these kind of errors there's errors involved that `valgrind` will pick up. These are accesses out of range and uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 1):

Many memory managers initialise memory to a known bad value to expose problems like this (e.g. Microsoft's CRT will use a range of values (0xCD means uninitialised, 0xDD means already free etc).

After each use of malloc, try memset'ing the memory to 0xCD (or some other constant value).  This will allow you to identify uninitialised memory more easily with the debugger.  don't use 0x00 as this is a 'normal' value and will be harder to spot if it's wrong (it will also probably 'fix' your problem).

Something like:

```
void *memory = malloc(sizeof(my_object));
memset(memory, 0xCD, sizeof(my_object));
```

If you know the size of the blocks, you could do something similar before free (this is sometimes harder unless you know the size of your objects, or track it in some way):

```
memset(memory, 0xDD, sizeof(my_object));
free(memory);
```